# Java Regular Expressions "\\d[a-zA-z]?"

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression in Java : `\\d[a-zA-z]` ?

It should only allow letters followed by 1 or 0 character.

However when I match it with, for example, 17c or even 21, it does not result in a match. This is the code I use:

```
if (!(pattern.matches("\\d[a-zA-z]?"))) {
      Throw error...;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `pattern`? Is `pattern` an input string? Also, I think *It should only allow **digits** followed by 1 or 0 **letter***. You only allow 1 digit with `\d`, and then 1 letter (note there is a typo, it must be `[A-Za-z]`). To allow 1+ digits, use `\d+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's because `17c` and `21` don't match `"\d[a-zA-z]?"`. This expression matches one digit followed by a character.

Try to use `"\d+[a-zA-z]*"` which matches one or more digits followed by zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

> It should only allow letters followed by 1 or 0 character.

Try with this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]+.?
```

Here:

- `[a-zA-Z]+` matches at least one letter (upper and lower case)
- `.?` matches any character (except newline) zero or one times.

Answer (score 0):

possibility \d+[a-zA-Z]? the one you are looking